# Javascript three.js shadow map with noise why?

Tags: javascript

When i turn on renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true - [screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zbtA.jpg), if false - [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngyxn.png).
Why there was noise ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to shadow algorithm.
Try to add:

`renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;`

or

`renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;`

And increase your light source shadowmap size:

```
<lightSource>.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
<lightSource>.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
```

Answer (score 0):

closed helped me

```
<lightSource>.shadow.bias = -0.0005;
```